# In django-rest-framework, how can I have a resource that is only editable by the user that created it?

Tags: django, permissions, django-rest-framework

If I have this:

```
class Image(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

how can I write a resource that will allow GET from anyone, but PUT only when `request.user` is the same as `image.user`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a permission that your modelviewset uses

```
class CreatorPermissions(BasePermission):
    def has_permission(self, request, view):
        return request.method in permissions.SAFE_METHOD

    def has_object_permission(self, request, view, obj):
        return request.user.id == obj.user.id

class ImageViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    model = Image
    serializer_class = ImageSerializer # you have to create this
    permission_classes = (CreatorPermissions,)
    queryset = Image.objects.all()
```